# Scraped content from my website posted on Blogspot is outranking my site and causing Google penalty

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, spam, negative-seo, scraper-sites

I noticed that starting from October the organic traffic is very low on my website. I searched on Google for some text phrases from my website and I noticed that there is a Blogspot website, a blog that copied 10 articles from my website. They copied the title and 70% of the article content.

The articles appeared on that website  two or three days after they appeared on my website. So my website is the first one where the articles appeared.

I guess that this is negative SEO, and my website is banned from Google because of this website. Please tell me where can I report that website in order to regain my position in Google Search.

I tried this website: https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/ , but I haven't received any answer from Google.
I also reported that website for badware on the website stopbadware.org.

Do you know what else can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that reason to ban your site by google is that copy scam only? Because there could be a lot of reason because of google ban site..

Comment: The website is not actually "banned". It just don't appear anymore in search results.

Comment: Ok then I think you should check other aspect also first , please refer : https://seo-hacker.com/banned-by-google-penalty-and-what-to-do/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not normal that your site is outranking you, but can happen.

Google has its own tool to report Scrapped content, you can check it here -> https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Pw1KVOVRyr4a7ezj_6SHghnX1Y6bp1SOVmy60QjkF0Y/viewform

I also advise you to make a DMCA complaint, as addresses copyright issues and can act faster. I had that experience in the past and it was fast enough. You can access it here -> https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en

There's also a lot of articles and documentation, even from Matt Cuts about the subject, I found a good article with relevant information [here](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/news/2331472/matt-cutts-submit-scraper-sites-that-outrank-you-on-google).

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear that blogger and blogspot are owned by Google.   Using the Google support link above is Google's proceedure for removing copyright content from those Google properties.

Comment: I know that these services are owned by Google. It seems that there are also some bad persons who also know this and they profit..

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this page:  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform?hl=en

Hope it will help others to protect against fake websites and scams.